# Xcode 10 beta error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode10

This is the complete error:

```
ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea what is this about, I'm using Xcode 10 beta, and iOS 11.4.1,
I have no "pods" project or anything like that, when I try to run the command:

`pod install`

I get the command not found.

I'm not using any additional tools or anything, so I'm only using npm and xcode command line commands.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(I post the solution here for all those who googled "cocoapods lstdc xcode 10" since this is the first page that hits.)

If you are using cocoa pods and got a similar error then the solution is to delete `-l"stdc++.6"` from your xcconfig files. Now build and run. Xcode10 build should succeed now :)

Cocoa pods is for some reason adding stdc so it gets linked, but that is not be needed and Xcode10 does not have that library anymore.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this!! BTW do you know what stdc lib does?

Comment: I think It does the same as "c++" lib but is the old version. BTW, this is not fault of cocoa pods, a library dependency is the one who is causing this. cocoa pods is just obeying.

Answer (score 1):

Libstdc++ was deprecated, the support was removed from the iOS 12 simulator (not for device).

One of the library in the pod file have a dependency builded with libstdc++, you can try to find a more recent version builded with the libc++.