# Xcode 10 - Build project failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just updated my Xcode to version 10. And when i build my project it shows me error

```
ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6.0.9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have been trying to clean project for many times but still not work for me.

Anyone has solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10 beta error: linker command failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367990/xcode-10-beta-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 10 removed support for -lstdc++. So check in your project settings under 'BuildPhases -> Link Binary With Libraries ' and remove the -lstdc++ dependency. If you use a 3rd party library which depends on -lstdc++ then you would need to ask to get a new version without this dependency.
Also check: 
[Xcode 10 (iOS 12) does not contain libstdc++6.0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694822/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9?rq=1)

Comment: Now it throws me another error `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: So then you might actually have a dependency on libstdc++ .

Comment: You meant when I remove libstdc++, and it throws me another error that mean i have some libraries which depend on it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the derived data, paste this into your termnial:

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```